# Auth0 Authenticate client App to consume external API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a `SPA` in *React* that make calls to an external `API` like:
`GET https://myapi.com/api/items/1` or `GET https://myapi.com/api/items/`.

In `myapi.com` server, the routes are secured with *oAuth2* using `express-jwt` and `auth0-api-jwt-rsa-validation`, son only calls with `Header: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + token }` respond with a status 200.

If I'll consume these calls from a server side application I could obtain the `token` from `POST https://myapi.auth0.com/oauth/token` passing `client_id, client_secret, grant_type and audience`. But since the application is *client-side* I think there's a best approach, avoiding to expose `client_secret` and so on.

I tried the [implicit-grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/implicit-grant) approach but I am dealing with the `callback_uri` and other confusing stuff.

The main idea is to allow the *Application*, say `https//myapp.com/list`  to consume the `API` like `GET https://myapi.com/api/items` (without users, without passwords).

The points:

- how to **Authenticate** the *Application* without users
- which and where make the call to `oAuth2` in my Application? (`onEnter` the top level route, on `componentDidMount`?) and
- how the token is in the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I [asked](https://community.auth0.com/questions/2433/auth0-authemticate-react-client-app-to-consume-ext) this question in the *Auth0 Community* I think could be useful for other to share the [answer](https://community.auth0.com/questions/2433/auth0-authemticate-react-client-app-to-consume-ext?childToView=2550#answer-2550).

For my usecase, the mos important part is

> You reached the right conclusions; the use of the token endpoint either for client credentials grants or resource owner password grant (ROPC) is not recommended for a SPA [...] This means that **if you want a SPA to access an API without the notion of a user, then that API needs to be public.**

So, in my case I'll make the API public or think in some user/password implementation.